# H.264 coded NAL/slice splitting

Tags: c++, video-streaming, h.264

I'm working on an application that needs to transfer an H.264-encoded video in a real-time over UDP (a sort of a video call).

Recently we've switched to a hardware encoder, which supports only a limited number of H.264 profiles. As the result, each encoded video frame now consists of a single NALu. More precisely, for IDR (key) frames the encoder produces SSP, PSP and a single IDR slice, for others - a single non-IDR slice.

Now, my goal is to split the slice NALu into several smaller ones, because in case of a packet loss if the NALu can't be assembled completely - it's totally lost. At minimum I need to split the slice spatially, i.e. put ranges of macroblocks into different NALus. If possible - I'd also like to extract quality layers, so that the base layer can be protected by more redundant packets (FEC).

Note: I'm not talking about transcoding. It's about repacking/reformatting, locating the macroblock definition data chunks and putting them in a different way.

I'm now trying to parse the appropriate data headers: SPS, PPS and coded slices, using both H.264 standard specs and some open-source decoders code. The task seems possible, though kinda tricky, with a lot of technical details.

My question is: is this a known problem? Is there some API/library that does exactly that?

Comment: You should post the model of the hardware encoder, someone might know how to configure it to produce NALu smaller than a value (like MTU). For FEC you can use RTP. You can see [RFC 6184](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184#section-6.1) for common packetization rules and [RFC  5109](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5109) for FEC.

Comment: @aergistal - thanks, we already use FEC and transmit via RTP (using ffmpeg). However this situation is all-or-nothing, either the whole NALu is fully recovered or not. Whereas I'd like to have several smaller NALus to be able to recover a part of the frame.

Comment: @valdo What do you mean by "is this a known problem?"

Comment: For your objective of repacking a single NALu into multiple packets can be achieved by [RTP FU Packetization mode](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184#section-5.8)

Comment: @ARK No, this is different. This kind of fragmentation + error correction leads to all-or-nothing. Either the whole NALu transferred or not. Whereas I want to be able to restore the encoded frame partially.

Comment: @valdo Got it; if your objective is to recover part of frame (in case of packet loss), FU packetization mode is not helpful. What you are trying to do is quite a feat. I am well aware of the intricacies involved for such a task as I have worked on H264 decoder (including error recovery and concealment) for quite some years. BTW, is your solution happened to be a closed loop solution? I can suggest an approach if it is a closed loop solution

Comment: @ARK You mean, something like sending NACK? It's also an option, but anyway I'd like to accomplish what I'm doing now. P.S. can you please describe in several words what you mean by "error recovery and concealment"?

Comment: @valdo I don't mean NACK, I meant whether the streams get decoded by a decoder (that generally provided by solution provider)? If encoder and decoders provided by single supplier, for an application/solution, it is possible to use some non-standard metadata to communicate specific details

Comment: @ARK Well, using non-standard metadata is possible, we don't need to conform to a standard. Can you please describe in general the "error concealment" strategy you worked on? I mean, was it something related to image recovery after decoding, or something related to fixing the bitstream before it gets decoded?

Comment: @valdo the error concealment strategy is mostly related to image recovery after decoding and partly to fixing some syntax during the course of decoding.

Comment: @ARK I see. Thanks. I'm also going to (try to) implement a sort of an error concealment, but by fixing the data *before* it enters the decoder. One of the ideas is it generate motion vectors to missing macroblocks by interpolating motion vectors of surrounding ones. But before I can start, I must be able to decode/encode the bitstream. I think about taking some open-source decoder code as the base.

Comment: One NALu - what a horror! I don't believe there any libraries which help you to solve the problem.  Are you stuck with that particular encoder? Also, what are the latency requirements? Can you afford to decode CABAC on the server?

Comment: @smirnoff it's a hardware encoder, and it seems not to support profiles with multiple NALus. Yes, I can afford CABAC decoding, but anyway the encoder doesn't seem to use entropy coding.

Comment: @valdo - any luck with this?

Comment: @valdo, were you able to solve this? I'm too stuck with the same problem for so long.

Comment: 7 years after: seems like most of h264 codecs simply don't support slicing , or giving too little control over maximum size of NAL units.  
AFAIK, the data in NAL units are entropy-encoded - it is compressed. This means you cannot simply split compressed data buffer into smaller chunks nilly-willy and then recombine it later, when there are some losses during transporting the data. The decompressor on receiving side will be very unhappy about it. This means you probably will need to decompress and then compress the data again using different maximum block size.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: is this a known problem? Is there some API/library that does exactly that?"

There is no API library that I know for, but I believe that you can find your solution, or close to your solution here in the source code that could be compiled into the library from the h264bitstream project at github: https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream/blob/master/svc_split.c
Let us know how it worked for you. Naturally, you have to do get some code reading here, but the basic solution, or close to the solution seems to be there.